# animation in text, hide text right to left is mounted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do a animation in text, hide text right to left, but the letters is mounted after animation...
I know that I can use a `white-space: nowrap` but I need it see as a paragraph

how I can animated this text without mounted letters?

[JSfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/f4yzomc1/1/)

```js
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#title").animate({width: 'hide'});
            $("#description").animate({width: 'hide'});
            $("#text1").animate({width: 'hide'});
        },2000);
```

```css
.bold{
    font-size: 48px;
    color: black;
    width: 400px;
}
.normal{
    font-size: 48px;
    color: black;
    width: 400px;
}
#container{
    width: 452px;
    height: 625px;
}
#description{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#description,#text1{
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" >
        <div id="title" class="bold">
            1231231231123
        </div>
        <div id="description"class="normal">asd asd as da sd asdfsdfasdfasd asd fsadf asdf asdfasdf.</div>
        <div id="text1" class="bold">
            aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `hide('slow');` almost gives that result, hope it helps, still thinking. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dW8Rv/1/ solves your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/dRpWv/309/ or this?

Comment: @odedta thanx for the first example, i can try it.... could serve because it is a paragraph http://jsfiddle.net/dW8Rv/1/   
the second example no .. it is the same : http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/821/

Comment: @odedta sorry, the first example isn't i want, I don't want move the text, I want hide right to left.. this effect

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible depending on your layout, you should animate `#container`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#container").animate({
        width: 'hide'
    });
}, 2000);
```

> [Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/ocm1d6oe/)

Comment: good solution... I had not thought of this,It was very simple.. jajajajaja